# Kubernetes clusterRole creation permission

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, rbac

I am using helm to install [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) on our GKE instance and while doing the :

```
helm install stakater/reloader --generate-name
```

i'm getting this response :

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "Myuser@mymail" cannot create resource "clusterroles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope: requires one of ["container.clusterRoles.create"] permission(s).
```

how can i resolve this issue via the GCP console ?

Comment: The user account you are using when running helm needs the `cluster-admin` role.